# Domain and Entity Models, their validation and complexity overhead

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, domain-driven-design

I'm designing a project and I just can't figured out how to correctly implement the DDD pattern in this case. I'm using MVC 5 and EF 6.

I understand the difference between an Entity Model and a Domain Model, but every time I stop to consider the DDD architecture applicability on my project, I can't shake the feeling that what I'm doing doesn't make a lot of sense, because my domain models always (or 99.99% of the time) end up being a plain clone of the entity.

I decided to separate the system into 2 projects: Application.Domain and Application.WebUI.

In my Application.Domain, I defined my entities, and all the persistence logic.

I have a User entity defined as follow (some field omitted for brevity)

```
User
 -Id
 -FirstName
 -LastName
 -PhoneNumber
 -Email
 -Sex
 -PasswordHash
```

and I have the entity configuration on a separate file, using EF Fluent API. Here is an excerpt:

```
ToTable("Users");
HasKey(p => p.Id);

Property(p => p.Email)
    .HasMaxLength(150)
    .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName,
    new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Email")));
```

Now in the Application.WebUI project, I will have my domain models that will "represent" the entity models.

What happens, as I said before, is that the domain model of the user will be 100% equal the entity model (except for the validation attributes I will use to validade user inputs), because I need all the properties, and a view model would look exactly the same as the domain model.
It just feels wrong to have view model mapped to domain model mapped to entity model to then store it.

Moreover, if I ever need to change the max length of the email to somethingo ther than 150, I will have to change it on the configuration file, **and** in the domain model validation.

It feels like I'm headed for a whole lot of useless mapping overhead and validation duplication. So, what am I missing?

Comment: If the domain model maps directly to the entity model, then do you need the entity model? Can you map the ORM to the Domain Model? I am not advising this - just asking.

Comment: What is the purpose of your 'domain' model? How are you using it and why do you think you need it?

Comment: @victor why only two projects and why would the domain model be in the UI layer?

Answer (score 2):

> It feels like I'm headed for a whole lot of useless mapping overhead and validation duplication. So, what am I missing?

The main thing that you may be missing is that the domain model and the persisted model change at a different cadence.  Today's model should continue to work with last year's data.

You are supposed to be able to change the domain model aggressively (think "continuous deploy"), but you probably don't want to migrate your database schema every time you deploy a new version.

The data structures that are most effective for load and store may not be those most suitable for the in memory manipulations by your domain model.

You may also be missing the fact that, although the persisted model and domain model are logically separate things, you don't neccessarily need to treat them differently *today*.  It's a perfectly reasonable to notice that (a) the two representations appear to be the same right now, and (b) treating them the same now means the current release cycle is faster, and (c) if the project is successful, and if we need to separate the different logical representations, we'll know a lot more about separating them in the future than we do now, and therefore YAGNI.

*Do be sure* to [document your decision](http://thinkrelevance.com/blog/2011/11/15/documenting-architecture-decisions), and the forces as your understood them at the time, so that you have a trail to follow if the circumstances change.

Comment: I can't see how any of the Data Access Layer entities, which map directly to the database tables, will ever be different from its Domain model that maps to the DAL entities. I can see, however, how a view model in the MVC Application Layer that maps to one or more Domain models could be different than a Domain model. Do you have an example?